# how to center an image without a fixed width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to center images that will not have a fixed width as its a gallery with various image sizes so cannot use margin 0 auto as you need a fixed width for that.

Is there a jquery solution?

Comment: You don't need a 'fixed' width to use auto-margins. You just need an element that is displaying block and isn't filling the whole width of the parent. As images are replaced elements, they don't expand horizontally when they display as blocks.

Comment: Can you not just use text-align center on the containing div? A visual example would help us understand your problem further. For example you could be floating the images which is why they don't center...

Comment: Thanks DavidYouve answered this, heavy weekend, still trying to get my brain running.

Answer (score 7):

Use this to center the images:

```
.wrapper { /* your wrapper element */
    text-align:center;   
}
.wrapper img {
    display:inline-block;   
}
```

However, if the images are small enough in width to go side-by-side and fit in the wrapper, they will. You can get around this with extra markup like wrapper `<div>`s around the image or even `<br />`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wesley_murch/Cwed9/1/

Make sure to adjust the width in the demo to see what I mean.

**EDIT**: I was playing jsfiddle while this was answered in the comments :P

Answer (score 0):

Hmm --

Are you saying the image is too large for the canvas? If so...
have the canvas overflow:hidden;

```
if (image-width > canvas-width){
   offset = image-width - canvas-width;
   offset = offset / 2;
   image.left = -offset;
}
```

Comment: no i have a slideshow and some of the images will be 500px wide and some will be 600px but I have no control over the width but always want them to be in the middle of the #content which is 980px wide

Answer (score 0):

try with this style

#### HTML

```
<div>
    <img src="" height="155px" width="155px" style="float:left">
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
img {  
    display: table-cell; // this says treat this element like a table cell
    vertical-align:middle;   
}
```